# City's name or id of the chosen city using Google Places autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to use Google Places autocomplete API to search for locations through text search. Is it possible to a get the city name or the cityId of the chosen city in the autocomplete box, using the places autocomplete API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the `address_components` of the current place via `autocompleteInstance.getPlace()`

The component where the `types`- property (it's an array) contains the values `political` and `locality` usually is the city.

Example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var components=this.getPlace().address_components,city='n/a';
      if(components){
        for(var c=0;c<components.length;++c){
        console.log(components[c].types.join('|'))
          if(components[c].types.indexOf('locality')>-1
              &&
             components[c].types.indexOf('political')>-1
            ){
            city=components[c].long_name;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    alert(city)
  });
```

Comment: I am experimenting on this jsfiddle page[http://jsfiddle.net/qA29J ]. Could you kindly add your script to this page to show the results ? I tried but it is not working with your script appended.

Comment: Thanks, but though this is working now, for almost 30-40% cases I'm seeing n/a. Although the city name is there in the complete address. How to deal with those cases ?

Comment: you may geocode the location(using `getPlace().geometry.location`) to get more precise results